# Selenium Webdriver, check if multiple elements are enabled and interact with them if true

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have a page with 16 identical WebElements (buttons) which may or may not be present on the page. The buttons have the same functionality - removing a piece of data when clicked.  I need to:-

1. Check if the elements are visible to the user
2. If 1. is true, click on them to remove

My code currently:-

```
public void removeExistingPeriods() {

    List<WebElement> removeButtons = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".activeLink.removeBtn.btn.btn-warning"));
    if (removeButtons.size() == 0) {
        fail("No Remove buttons were found on the page!:");
    } else {
        for(WebElement option: removeButtons){
            option.click();
        }
    }

}
```

This fails with:-
    org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently  visible and so may not be interacted with

How can I:-

1. check how many buttons from the 16 total are enabled?
2. click on those that are enabled in turn until no more enabled buttons are present?

Comment: in else condition, before clicking the element, just check if(button.isDisplayed()), it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this.Using the enhanced for loop you loop over each WebElement in removedButtons. If the button `isDisplayed` then click it.

```
List<WebElement> removeButtons = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".activeLink.removeBtn.btn.btn-warning"));
for(WebElement button : removeButtons) {
  if(button.isDisplayed()) {
     button.click();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work :

```
public void removeExistingPeriods() {

List<WebElement> removeButtons = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".activeLink.removeBtn.btn.btn-warning"));
if (removeButtons.size()> 0 && removeButtons.isDisplayed()) {

        for(WebElement option: removeButtons){
        option.click();
      } 
      else 
      {

          fail("No Remove buttons were found on the page!:");


         }
      }

     }
```

I have just reverse if result and button checking condition.

Comment: No, this does not work as it does not check if buttons are enabled or not

Comment: I see , I have forgot to add condition for display. Check now updated code.

Answer (score -1):

I expecting that you are looking for enabled list of elements. Below code helps you

```
int totalEnabledElements = 0;

    try{

        List<WebElement> removeButtons = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".activeLink.removeBtn.btn.btn-warning"));
        if(removeButtons.size()>0){

            for(int i=0; i<removeButtons.size(); i++){

                if(removeButtons.get(i).isEnabled()==true){

                    removeButtons.get(i).click();
                    totalEnabledElements++;

                }else{
                    System.out.println("element not visible or hidden :" +removeButtons.get(i).getText());
                }

            }

            System.out.println("total enabled elements: " +totalEnabledElements);

        }else{

            System.out.println("No Remove buttons were found on the page!");
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
    }
```

in above code is used isEnabled() as you saying as enabled elements, if you are intend to check displayed elements then you can use isDisplayed.

Let me know, if i am wrong.

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: If you are getting a list of elements then `NoSuchElementException` are not thrown in the case of 'zero' elements with the chosen selector. It would work best to check is the list has a length greater than zero.